# Can't access project hosted on ip address from other devices on same wi-fi

Tags: macos, webpack, networking, localhost, frontend

I am a frontend developer and I have set up my projects to run on 192.XXX.X.X instead of localhost so I can access it from my phone.

Recently, this stopped working. On all projects.
Ones using webpack and ones using simple VSCode live-server.
Unfortunately I have issues troubleshooting because in the meantime I have installed a lot of things, so I am not sure what could be the culprit.

Most recent things I have done:

- Installed parallels
- Upgraded to Big Sur
- Realized that company provided VPN doesn't work on it
- Reverted back with TimeMachine to Catalina

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If your IP address is having following signatures 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16 don't feel shy to share your IP, no one will hack into your system since they are private address ranges (Unless hacker is on stackoveflow and sitting on the same subnet as you are).

Comment: @MohithReddy, fair point but I prefer to be on the safe side. I am aware of the chances being miniscule.